# What is the difference between \pnode and \psnode in the following example?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\newcommand{\hinhtron}[4]{
    \pscircle(0,0){1}
    \psline(1;45)(1;-135)
    \psline(1;-45)(1;135)
    \rput(.5,0){#1}
    \rput(0,.5){#2}
    \rput(-.5,0){#3}
    \rput(0,-.5){#4}
}

\psnode(-2,0){A}{\hinhtron{0}{1}{0}{}}
\ncline[nodesep=1cm]{->}{A}{B}
\naput{9} \nbput{$x_1$}
\pnodes(-2,0){L}
\pnode([nodesep=1,angle=15]A){Q}
\psdot(Q)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the letter **A** is replaced by **L**, so:

[image]

Comment: A `\pnode` is empty, a `\psnode` has a contents.

Comment: `pnodes` is also available.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Please, who are you, i don't know, you get out. :-)

Comment: I can read your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\psnode(x,y){name}{text}` is internally a `\rnode{name}{text}` and its coordinates
depend to the internally used `\rput(x,y){\rnode{name}{text}}`. That *could* be the same as the given `(x,y)` but *must not* be the same! Important is the center of what is given by the `text`, that will be the node `{name}`.